# C# windows media player event: when playlist has finished

Tags: c#, media-player

mp4 video files are in a folder. Files will change from time to time as new ones are added, old ones removed so it’s not a statis list.

I’m reading the files in the folder at runtime and loading an array with the filenames to create a playlist.  At the end of the last file in the playlist I want to use the wmp “play state change” event to fire another event to continue with other tasks after the last vid ends.

I can use the event successfully when I load the media player with individual files but it’s not behaving the same when a playlist is used.  It doesnt fire after the last video in the playlist finishes, Any ideas?  code below:

```
 public void wmp_PlayStateChange_1(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
        {
            if (wmp.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
            {
              wmp.Visible = false;
              counter = 0;
              ImageTimer.Enabled = true;
              ImageTimer.Start();
            }

        }
```

Slight clarification:  If theres only ONE video file in the folder, it fires the event.  But if there's more than ONE, it does NOT fire the event at the end.  I can;t tell what if anything it fires but its not this specific event.  Thanks!

Comment: When a playlist is playing, does it fire the event at all? I would think it would at the end of each track with `wmp.playState == WMPLIb.WMPPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded`. You may need to check if the track that ended is the last one in the playlist.

Comment: thanks for replying.  Its weird  - if theres just a single file in the folder it plays the file then fires the event.  but if the total number of files > 1 it never fires. "..MediaEnded" does not fire anything either.  Is there any plug-in or other way to see WHAT events the WMP control fires?